# Is it not recommendable to build a web application with a CMS?

Tags: php, web-applications, content-management-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To use Wordpress for developing a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576062/to-use-wordpress-for-developing-a-web-application)

For instance, I've been using WordPress to build websites and online communities for some time. Recently I've been wondering if I should try building web applications using WordPress, which may be a bit strange since WordPress is already a web application. I can't think of any drawbacks thought.

Is it not recommendable to build a web application with a CMS?

Comment: If it makes sense inside WordPress and you think it can work I say go for it. Something to think about though is that WordPress is constantly being updated so you may have to keep your app up to date along with it because holes in WordPress are being discovered all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plenty of people build web applications around the likes of Drupal and Wordpress, there's definitely no reason not to.

The main reason that you might not is because conforming to a CMS can mean reducing your flexibility however people do it so chances are, you can too.

Many people choose to go with a Web Application Framework (e.g. Zend Framework or Django) for developing with as it goes half way between a CMS and the pure language - offering some conveniences but not forcing you into a rigid structure.

Django, for example, even has a CMS built into it. It reads your models and builds a CMS around those.

Answer (score 2):

There is often no reason **not** to build your web application with a CMS. Generally you would let the CMS handle the dynamic content of the site.

It is probably better to think of the CMS as being a part of your site, rather than your site being built in the CMS. You can still have your custom pages and other aspects with most CMS solutions. They also can offer a nice looking administration area if you need one for the site.

Another decent .Net CMS is Umbraco which I have had some success with.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of CMSs *as* Web Apps. That is what they are. And like any other web app they can be built on a solid framework (or not). The only real difference is that most CMS "platforms" started life as a CMS and evolved into a platform/framework (= bloat); whereas, most frameworks have been built specifically with no main application in mind - so they tend to be lighter.

The answer really lies in whether or not that framework, or foundation, is really a good starting point for your application. Also whether or not you need the CMS functionality as part of your app.

IMHO, CMSs have a lot of bloat and they're not the best starting point, so use a CMS *ONLY* if content's a **core aspect** of the finished product, otherwise use [a framework](http://github.com/flipstorm/eddy).

Remember: you can always build two separate systems tuned for their specific functions if you use a CMS for the content and a framework for your app. It's harder to refine a single system for two purposes.