# Integrate a web application into a WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to develop a web application, and I will use PHP to do it. I have a web server where I have hosted a WordPress blog and my database.

I have in mind to place the static pages in the WordPress blog (home, contact form, about us, login, and register page...) and then, after the login, the user would be redirected to the web application.

I don't want the design to change from the WordPress blog to the application (menus, footer, etc.). Is this possible?

Comment: I am looking for feedback of more experient web application developers about the idea of integrate a php application into a wordpress site.

Comment: It depends on how complicated is your application, can you integrate it as a Wordpress plugin ?

Comment: I don't think I can solve it with an wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible (theoretically—I have no idea what your application will be), but developing both pieces together (WordPress theme + application) will be easier than trying to cram a separately developed application into a pre-existing WordPress theme.

It is possible to customize a theme by editing the source files to display your application where you want it. (Bear in mind there may be license restrictions if you have purchased or otherwise downloaded the theme from someone.)

There is a good discussion on this topic here: *[To use WordPress for developing a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576062/to-use-wordpress-for-developing-a-web-application)*

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project!